# Calculate amount of occurences for column per category

Tags: r, count, data.table

I'm trying to calculate the amount of occurences of "Opp" in the iets column per SNP name (eventually I want to divide the amount of occurences of "Opp" by df$MM.)

```
library(data.table)
df <- structure(list(SNP = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("rs80932150", "rs000001"), class = "factor"), FID = c(116601888L, 116621563L, 117253533L, 118635095L, 118943247L), IID = c(116601888L, 116621563L, 117253533L, 118635095L, 118943247L), NEW = structure(c(16L, 14L, 16L, 14L, 14L), .Label = c("A/A", "A/C", "A/G", "A/T", "C/A", "C/C", "C/G", "C/T", "G/A", "G/C", "G/G", "G/T", "T/A", "T/C", "T/G", "T/T"), class = "factor"), OLD = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("A/A", "A/C", "A/G", "A/T", "C/A", "C/C", "C/G", "C/T", "G/A", "G/C", "G/G", "G/T", "T/A", "T/C", "T/G", "T/T"), class = "factor"), count = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), MM = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L), iets = c("Opp", "Het", "Opp", "Het", "Het")), .Names = c("SNP", "FID", "IID", "NEW", "OLD", "count", "MM", "iets"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
setDT(df)

#         SNP       FID       IID NEW OLD count MM iets
#1 rs80932150 116601888 116601888 T/T C/C     1  4  Opp
#2 rs80932150 116621563 116621563 T/C C/C     1  4  Het
#3 rs80932150 117253533 117253533 T/T C/C     1  4  Opp
#4   rs000001 118635095 118635095 T/C C/C     1  1  Het
#5 rs80932150 118943247 118943247 T/C C/C     1  4  Het
```

My expected result would be the following:

```
df
#          SNP       FID       IID NEW OLD count MM iets oppcount percentage
#1: rs80932150 116601888 116601888 T/T C/C     1  4  Opp      2        0.5
#2: rs80932150 116621563 116621563 T/C C/C     1  4  Het      2        0.5
#3: rs80932150 117253533 117253533 T/T C/C     1  4  Opp      2        0.5
#4:   rs000001 118635095 118635095 T/C C/C     1  1  Het      0        0.0
#5: rs80932150 118943247 118943247 T/C C/C     1  4  Het      2        0.5
```

I've been trying things similar to this, however I can't seem to figure out how to assign the occurence values to my oppcount/percentage column.
First I would have to count the amount of "Opp" per SNP, and then divide it by MM.

```
as.character((sum(df$iets == "Opp")/(df[,.N, by = df$SNP][[2]])))
#[1] "0.5" "2"
```

How can I calculate the amount of occurences of "Opp" per SNP (category)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update your `data.table` by reference with the `:=` operator. With:

```
df[, `:=` (oppcount = sum(iets=='Opp'), percentage = sum(iets=='Opp')/.N), by = SNP]
```

you get:

```
> df
          SNP       FID       IID NEW OLD count MM iets oppcount percentage
1: rs80932150 116601888 116601888 T/T C/C     1  4  Opp        2        0.5
2: rs80932150 116621563 116621563 T/C C/C     1  4  Het        2        0.5
3: rs80932150 117253533 117253533 T/T C/C     1  4  Opp        2        0.5
4:   rs000001 118635095 118635095 T/C C/C     1  1  Het        0        0.0
5: rs80932150 118943247 118943247 T/C C/C     1  4  Het        2        0.5
```

Or, based on the suggestion by @Frank in the comments, you could also use one of the following two options:

```
# method 1
df[, c('oppcount', 'percentage') := {s = sum(iets=='Opp'); .(s, s/.N)}, by = SNP]
# method 2
df[df[, {s = sum(iets=='Opp'); .(oppcount = s, percentage = s/.N)}, by = SNP], on = 'SNP']
```

---

A base R alternative:

```
transform(df,
          oppcount = ave(iets, SNP, FUN = function(x) sum(x=='Opp')),
          percentage = ave(iets, SNP, FUN = function(x) sum(x=='Opp')/length(x)))
```

---

A correct `dplyr` alternative would be:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(SNP) %>% 
  mutate(oppcount = sum(iets=='Opp'),
         percentage = oppcount/n())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rs8.oppcount<-length(iets[iets=='Opp' & SNP=='rs80932150'])
rs0.oppcount<-length(iets[iets=='Opp' & SNP=='rs000001'])
```

This saves the occurences of Opp for the snp categories!

EDIT:

```
df1<-group_by(df, df$SNP)
df2<-summarise(df1, oppcount = length(iets[iets=='Opp']))
df1<-merge(df1, df2, by = 'SNP')
```

Does that work?

Comment: This is a first step, however my actual dataset contains approx 100K rows with a total of ~20K different SNPs. I'm looking for a solution which will work regardless of the SNP name.

Comment: I hope the reordering per SNP group doesn't matter

Comment: unfortunately not, > df2<-summarise(df1, oppcount = length(iets[iets=='Opp']))
> df1<-merge(df1, df2, by = 'SNP')
Error in merge.data.table(df1, df2, by = "SNP") : 
  Elements listed in `by` must be valid column names in x and y
. I can't get it to work, df2 has a column named `df2$df$SNP`.

Comment: Reordering the SNP groups doesn't matter, I can simply `match()` to get them back where they belong!

Comment: Fyi, a standard way of counting instances where a condition holds is `sum(cond(x))` rather than `length(x[ cond(x) ])`, as seen in the accepted answer. Dplyr has additional conveniences functions for this, I think.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `dplyr`?

```
library('dplyr')
df %>% group_by(iets, SNP) %>% summarize(count=sum(count)) %>% filter(iets=='Opp')
```

Comment: This yields only one row with the example, which doesn't include the rs id with only "Het".